# Ordering by category id and price on index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I’m having trouble with ordering my houses. I have a houses that belong_to category (category has_many houses) and I want to order the houses on the index based on their category_id, but whatever I try it doesn’t seem to change the order. It’s a mystery to me. Maybe you could help me out?

```
class HousesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index, :show]
  before_action :set_house, only: [ :show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :inquiry ]
​
  def index
    # byebug
    @houses = policy_scope(House).order(:name)
    @houses = params.has_key?(:h) ? index_result(@houses) : @houses
    # split_categories(@houses)
  end
​
  def index_result(houses)
    # byebug
    wall_thickness = params[:h].to_i
    if wall_thickness == 1
      houses.order(:name)
      render "results_index_all"
    elsif wall_thickness == 28 || 40
      houses = houses.where(:wall => wall_thickness)
      houses.order(:name)
      render "results_index"
    else
    end
  end
​
  def split_categories(houses)
    # @houses_1 = @houses.where(price_cents: 0...260000)
    # @houses_2 = @houses.where(price_cents: 260000..1000000)
    # byebug
    category = Category.find_by(id: params[:category])
    houses = @category.present? ? category.houses.order(price_cents: :asc) : houses
  end
​
  def show
  end
​
  def new
    @house = House.new
    authorize @house
  end
​
  def create
    @house = House.new(house_params)
    @house.user = current_user
    authorize @house
    if @house.save
      redirect_to house_path(@house)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
​
  def edit
  end
​
  def update
    if @house.update(house_params)
      redirect_to house_path(@house)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
​
  def destroy
    @house.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end
​
  private
​
  def set_house
    @house = House.friendly.find(params[:id])
    authorize @house
  end
​
  def house_params
    params.require(:house).permit(:sku, :name, :price_cents, :width, :length, :wall, pictures: [])
  end
​
end
```

Below is the normal index where I split houses up in categories starting with category_id: 2 (normal garden houses), then 1 (gazebos) and finally 3 (garages). This is partial which is rendered app/views/houses/index.html.erb

```
<% if !@category %>
<%= render 'first-banner-home' %>
  <div class="container catalog">
    <%= render "filter_buttons" %>
    <div class="row">
      <% @houses.where(category_id: 2).each do |house| %>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <% if house.pictures? %>
            <div class="imageTop" style="position: relative;">
              <%= cl_image_tag(house.pictures[0], :quality=>50, :width=>1800, :crop=>"scale", class: "card-img-top", alt: house.name + " " + house.category.name) %>
              <%= link_to "", house_path(house), class: "card-link" %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <div class="card-body indexBody">
            <div class="card-price">
              <h3 class="card-title"><%= house.name %></h3>
              <h3><%= house.length.to_f / 100 %> x <%= house.width.to_f.to_f / 100 %> m</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-price">
            <% if house.price_present == false %>
                <h3><%= t('show.consult') %></h3>
            <% else %>
                <h3><%= humanized_money_with_symbol(house.original_price) %><span style="color: red"> - 15%</span> = <%= humanized_money_with_symbol(house.price) %></h3>
              <% end %>
            </div>
            <% if policy(house).update? %>
              <%= link_to "Edit", edit_house_path(house) %>
            <% end %>
            <% if policy(house).destroy? %>
              <%= link_to "Remove", house_path(house), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container catalog">
    <h3><%= t('home.gazebos') %></h3>
    <div class="row">
      <% @houses.where(category_id: 1).each do |house| %>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
          <% if house.pictures? %>
            <div class="imageTop" style="position: relative;">
              <%= cl_image_tag(house.pictures[0], :quality=>50, :width=>1800, :crop=>"scale", class: "card-img-top-alt", alt: house.name + " " + house.category.name) %>
              <%= link_to "", house_path(house), class: "card-link" %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <div class="card-body indexBody">
            <div class="card-price">
              <h3 class="card-title"><%= house.name %></h3>
              <h3><%= house.length.to_f / 100 %> x <%= house.width.to_f.to_f / 100 %> m</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-price">
            <% if house.price_present == false %>
                <h3><%= t('show.consult') %></h3>
            <% else %>
                <h3><%= humanized_money_with_symbol(house.original_price) %><span style="color: red"> - 15%</span> = <%= humanized_money_with_symbol(house.price) %></h3>
              <% end %>
            </div>
            <% if policy(house).update? %>
              <%= link_to "Edit", edit_house_path(house) %>
            <% end %>
            <% if policy(house).destroy? %>
              <%= link_to "Remove", house_path(house), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container catalog">
    <h3><%= t('home.garages') %></h3>
    <div class="row">
      <% @houses.where(category_id: 3).each do |house| %>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
          <% if house.pictures? %>
            <div class="imageTop" style="position: relative;">
              <%= cl_image_tag(house.pictures[0], :quality=>50, :width=>1800, :crop=>"scale", class: "card-img-top-alt", alt: house.name + " " + house.category.name) %>
              <%= link_to "", house_path(house), class: "card-link" %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <div class="card-body indexBody">
            <div class="card-price">
              <h3 class="card-title"><%= house.name %></h3>
              <h3><%= house.length.to_f / 100 %> x <%= house.width.to_f.to_f / 100 %> m</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-price">
            <% if house.price_present == false %>
                <h3><%= t('show.consult') %></h3>
            <% else %>
                <h3><%= humanized_money_with_symbol(house.original_price) %><span style="color: red"> - 15%</span> = <%= humanized_money_with_symbol(house.price) %></h3>
              <% end %>
            </div>
            <% if policy(house).update? %>
              <%= link_to "Edit", edit_house_path(house) %>
            <% end %>
            <% if policy(house).destroy? %>
              <%= link_to "Remove", house_path(house), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= render "last-banner" %>
<% elsif params[:h].present? %>
  <%= render "results_index" %>
<% else %>
  <%= render "category_index" %>
<% end %>
```

This is the index where the houses are filtered based on their wall thickness (see in app/controllers/houses_controller.rb ). This is where I want the house to order based on their category_id, which doesn’t work at the moment.

```
<% content_for(:title) do %><%= t('topbar.brand') %><% end %>
<% content_for(:og_site_name) do %><%= t('topbar.brand') %><% end %>
<% content_for(:description) do %><%= t('garden_houses.meta_description') %><% end %>
<% content_for(:og_image) do %><%= cl_image_path("https://res.cloudinary.com/www-ibizagardenhouses-com/image/upload/c_scale,h_630,w_1200/v1558696079/ibi-3/image.jpg") %><% end %>
<% content_for(:og_description) do %><%= t('garden_houses.meta_description') %><% end %>
<%= render 'first-banner-results' %>
<% if @houses.count >= 4 %>
  <div class="container catalog">
    <%= render "filter_buttons" %>
    <div class="row">
      <% @houses.each do |house| %>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <% if house.pictures? %>
            <div class="imageTop" style="position: relative;">
              <%= cl_image_tag(house.pictures[0], :quality=>50, :width=>1800, :crop=>"scale", class: "card-img-top", alt: house.name + " " + house.category.name) %>
              <%= link_to "", house_path(house), class: "card-link" %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <div class="card-body indexBody">
            <div class="card-price">
              <h3 class="card-title"><%= house.name %></h3>
              <h3><%= house.length.to_f / 100 %> x <%= house.width.to_f.to_f / 100 %> m</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-price">
            <% if house.price_present == false %>
                <h3><%= t('show.consult') %></h3>
            <% else %>
                <h3><%= humanized_money_with_symbol(house.original_price) %><span style="color: red"> - 15%</span> = <%= humanized_money_with_symbol(house.price) %></h3>
              <% end %>
            </div>
            <% if policy(house).update? %>
              <%= link_to "Edit", edit_house_path(house) %>
            <% end %>
            <% if policy(house).destroy? %>
              <%= link_to "Remove", house_path(house), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= render "last-banner" %>
<% else %>
  <div class="container catalog">
    <%= render "filter_buttons" %>
    <div class="row">
      <% @houses.each do |house| %>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
          <% if house.pictures? %>
            <div class="imageTop" style="position: relative;">
              <%= cl_image_tag(house.pictures[0], :quality=>50, :width=>1800, :crop=>"scale", class: "card-img-top-alt", alt: house.name + " " + house.category.name) %>
              <%= link_to "", house_path(house), class: "card-link" %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <div class="card-body indexBody">
            <div class="card-price">
              <h3 class="card-title"><%= house.name %></h3>
              <h3><%= house.length.to_f / 100 %> x <%= house.width.to_f.to_f / 100 %> m</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-price">
            <% if house.price_present == false %>
                <h3><%= t('show.consult') %></h3>
            <% else %>
                <h3><%= humanized_money_with_symbol(house.original_price) %><span style="color: red"> - 15%</span> = <%= humanized_money_with_symbol(house.price) %></h3>
              <% end %>
            </div>
            <% if policy(house).update? %>
              <%= link_to "Edit", edit_house_path(house) %>
            <% end %>
            <% if policy(house).destroy? %>
              <%= link_to "Remove", house_path(house), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= render "last-banner" %>
<% end %>
```

This is exactly the same html as app/views/houses/results_index.html.erb , but where I show all the houses (params[h: 1]) in a layout that’s not the same as the home page. Same problem here as on the filtered results page.

```
<% content_for(:title) do %><%= t('topbar.brand') %><% end %>
<% content_for(:og_site_name) do %><%= t('topbar.brand') %><% end %>
<% content_for(:description) do %><%= t('garden_houses.meta_description') %><% end %>
<% content_for(:og_image) do %><%= cl_image_path("https://res.cloudinary.com/www-ibizagardenhouses-com/image/upload/c_scale,h_630,w_1200/v1558696079/ibi-3/image.jpg") %><% end %>
<% content_for(:og_description) do %><%= t('garden_houses.meta_description') %><% end %>
<%= render 'first-banner-all' %>
<% if @houses.count >= 4 %>
  <div class="container catalog">
    <%= render "filter_buttons" %>
    <div class="row">
      <% @houses.each do |house| %>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <% if house.pictures? %>
            <div class="imageTop" style="position: relative;">
              <%= cl_image_tag(house.pictures[0], :quality=>50, :width=>1800, :crop=>"scale", class: "card-img-top", alt: house.name + " " + house.category.name) %>
              <%= link_to "", house_path(house), class: "card-link" %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <div class="card-body indexBody">
            <div class="card-price">
              <h3 class="card-title"><%= house.name %></h3>
              <h3><%= house.length.to_f / 100 %> x <%= house.width.to_f.to_f / 100 %> m</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-price">
            <% if house.price_present == false %>
                <h3><%= t('show.consult') %></h3>
            <% else %>
                <h3><%= humanized_money_with_symbol(house.original_price) %><span style="color: red"> - 15%</span> = <%= humanized_money_with_symbol(house.price) %></h3>
              <% end %>
            </div>
            <% if policy(house).update? %>
              <%= link_to "Edit", edit_house_path(house) %>
            <% end %>
            <% if policy(house).destroy? %>
              <%= link_to "Remove", house_path(house), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= render "last-banner" %>
<% else %>
  <div class="container catalog">
    <%= render "filter_buttons" %>
    <div class="row">
      <% @houses.each do |house| %>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
          <% if house.pictures? %>
            <div class="imageTop" style="position: relative;">
              <%= cl_image_tag(house.pictures[0], :quality=>50, :width=>1800, :crop=>"scale", class: "card-img-top-alt", alt: house.name + " " + house.category.name) %>
              <%= link_to "", house_path(house), class: "card-link" %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <div class="card-body indexBody">
            <div class="card-price">
              <h3 class="card-title"><%= house.name %></h3>
              <h3><%= house.length.to_f / 100 %> x <%= house.width.to_f.to_f / 100 %> m</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-price">
            <% if house.price_present == false %>
                <h3><%= t('show.consult') %></h3>
            <% else %>
                <h3><%= humanized_money_with_symbol(house.original_price) %><span style="color: red"> - 15%</span> = <%= humanized_money_with_symbol(house.price) %></h3>
              <% end %>
            </div>
            <% if policy(house).update? %>
              <%= link_to "Edit", edit_house_path(house) %>
            <% end %>
            <% if policy(house).destroy? %>
              <%= link_to "Remove", house_path(house), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= render "last-banner" %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, there's a lot of duplication of code (not very DRY) and so I'd like a little help in getting more DRY and have the houses be ordered by category_id and then by price.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: you mention that you tried some stuff, what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you tried so far, but if all you need is to sort by `category_id`, I think you can define a [scope](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope) within your house model as follow:

```rb
scope :sort_by_category_id_asc, ->{
    order(arel_table[:category_id].asc)
  }
```

Then you can use that scope as follow: `House.where(...).sort_by_category_id_asc`, also you can use `desc`, depends on how you want to order the result.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I created a method that can sort houses by its `category_id`. If you want to sort it by other things just change category_id to your desired thing. You can sort it ascending or descending order. Here it is:

```
def sort_by_category_id(houses, order)
  case order_by
    when "asc"
      houses = houses.sort_by{ |house|
        house[:category_id]
      }
      
    when "desc"
      house= house.sort_by{ |house|
        house[:category_id]
      }.reverse!
  end
  house
end
```

Don't forget to call this method wherever you want it to be worked. Below code will sort your houses by category_id and save it in `sorted_houses` variable. I

```
sorted_houses_asc = sort_by_category_id(@houses, "asc")
sorted_houses_desc = sort_by_category_id(@houses, "desc")
```

Hope this helped you somehow.

Comment: That is a good solution, the downside of this is that you sort on memory instead of on the query to the db (at db level), keep in mind that if you have enough data this approach can slow you down @Minjin Gelegdorj, but definitely a valid approach

Comment: happy to help